# Can't get the cascading combo boxes to work

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, filtering, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to make cascading combo boxes but I can't seem to get it to work. For example, if I select a specific computer in the first combo box, then the second combo box should only show the HDD that is compatible with that computer. I also provided a link to the database that I have created. Can anyone help me out with this?

I have 2 tables with the fields:

- tblComputer(Computer)
- tblHDD(HDD, Computer)

**cboxComputer Row Source:** SELECT tblComputer.Computer FROM tblComputer;

**cboxHDD Row Source:** SELECT tblHDD.HDD, tblHDD.Computer FROM tblHDD;

```
Private Sub cboxComputer_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboxHDD.RowSource = "SELECT HDD " & _
                           "FROM tblHDD " & _
                           "WHERE Computer = " & Nz(Me.cboxComputer) & _
                           "ORDER BY HDD"
End Sub
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bye-M8FI1tRURmQ0MEFzRjBCdWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what does not work? is the cboxHDD not loading? is there error message?

Comment: Sorry for not including what was wrong. The second combo box does not work. When I select the second combo box, it says "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Computer = SonyORDER BY HDD'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Computer field in the database is a string datatype. Try putting apostrophes around the name like this:

```
Private Sub cboxComputer_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboxHDD.RowSource = "SELECT HDD " & _
                       "FROM tblHDD " & _
                       "WHERE Computer = '" & Nz(Me.cboxComputer) & "' " & _
                       "ORDER BY HDD"
End Sub
```

Comment: I type that in and it says "Compile error: Syntax error"

Comment: You also need a space after the closing apostrophe or before the word ORDER. I updated my answer to account for this.

Comment: I keep getting the same error message even if I added a space before the word ORDER. I also added a space after the closing apostrophe as well.

Comment: Ok, I omitted the last ampersand. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Awesome, this works! So if cboxComputer was a numeric data, then I do not have to put the apostrophe and quotation, correct?

Comment: Correct that you don't need the apostrophes. You need the quotes to concatenate a literal text string to the combo box. Also, date fields use # signs around them.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but what does the Nz mean in Nz(Me.cboxComputer) represent?

Comment: You can use the Nz function to return zero, a zero-length string (" "), or another specified value when a Variant is Null. For example, you can use this function to convert a Null value to another value and prevent it from propagating through an expression.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c