# Access database help - picking football games

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to create a database for picking football game winners.

Simply, I have a table of available games:

```
| GameID | AwayTeamName | HomeTeamName |
  1         Team1           Team2
  2         Team3           Team4
etc.
```

And

```
Table2

| GameID | MyPick |
    1       drop-down here
    2       drop-down here
etc.
```

I'm trying to have `MyPick` be a drop-down showing only the `AwayTeamName` and `HomeTeamName` for `GameID` for me to pick from.

I've tried using the lookup wizard to no avail as well as using a query.

I'm using Access 2019.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
I have created this SQL query:

```
SELECT [Raw Data].[AWAY TEAM] AS [SELECTION]
FROM [Raw Data]
WHERE [Raw Data].[Game ID] = 20191901
UNION ALL
SELECT [Raw Data].[HOME TEAM]
FROM [Raw Data]
WHERE [Raw Data].[Game ID] = 20191901
```

and it works perfectly. Now I just need to figure out how to send/tell the query to use the `Game ID` I'm currently working on.

CLARIFICATION:
I am using a form for data input. I already have the list of games loaded. I just need to be able to select from the two teams listed on the form.

The form is something like this:

```
Game ID

AwayTeam
Home Team

Pick the winner: _______________

First  Prev  Next  Last
```

I'm wanting to just have the two teams listed in the combobox for picking.

Comment: Part of query is missing. Your options for apply filter criteria are: 1) dynamic parameterized query that references combobox or 2) apply filter to form or report when opening. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cascading Combo box doesn't update 2nd box options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159176/cascading-combo-box-doesnt-update-2nd-box-options)